# Formik form won't clear out

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, formik

I was trying to populate the initialValue of my formik form with its hoc data onClick.
Clearing the form back to its first initialValue (initValues) when the reForm() is used does'nt work and it always goes back to the value from the prop.

parent:

```
const [contactData, setContactData] = useState();
.
..
....

<First userData={contactData}/>
<Second userData={setContactData}/>
```

child:

```
function FirstComponent({userData}) {
    const [isUpdate, setUpdate] = useState(false);
    const initValues = {
        id:'',
        email: '',
        name: '',
        contact: ''
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        // setContactData(userData)
        userData!==undefined ? setUpdate(true) : setUpdate(false);
        console.log("from form: ", userData)
    }, [userData]);
    
    const formik = useFormik({
        enableReinitialize: true,
        validationSchema: FormSchema,
        initialValues: userData || initValues,
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            // same shape as initial values
            console.log("the Data ", userData)
            console.log("onsubmit ", values);
        }
    })

    const resForm = () => {
        formik.initialValues = {initValues};
        console.log("prop ", userData)

        console.log("formik values ",formik.initialValues)
        formik.resetForm();
    }
```

Replacing the initialValues with initValues in formik.resetForm() seems to work, but it makes the form reinitialize back with the *userData* prop - `function FormComponent({userData})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

partially fixed..
just modified the `formik.resetForm()` in resForm() to

```
formik.resetForm({
  values:initValues
});
```

but the prop (userData) from parent still persists when console logged in resForm()

Comment: In your code you have just mentioned that reset the form values , but not the userData from the parent component . If you need to change the userData as well , then you need to pass a callback function from the parent to your `FirstComponent` .

Comment: I didn't think of that! thanks it worked :)